# Is it possible to construct a single query to match two tables enforcing a 1:1 relationship between them?

Tags: mysql, sql

For those interested in the reasoning behind this question: I have an e-commerce site that works fine, but has no gift certificate capabilities.  Adding monetary GCs should be pretty simple, but I'd also like to allow the gifting of specific products (sounds odd but is relevant to my industry).  So I plan to create a new table to house gift certificates that are linked to a specific user and product, and I need an efficient way to evaluate that table on the cart and checkout pages.

Imagine tables exist that look similar to the following:

```
CartContents
CartID          Integer (Unique sequential row identifier)
UserID          Integer
ProductID       Integer
Quantity        Integer

Gifts
GiftID          Integer (Unique sequential row identifier)  
ProductID       Integer
UserID          Integer
Quantity        Integer
```

This is an overly simplified layout, but demonstrates the idea.  The first table lists items in the user's cart; one record per product (though real products will have additional details that may vary).  The product table has further attributes on products but I don't list it here for simplicity.  The second table is a set of gift certificates, each for a specific product, that have been presented to this user ID.

Table data may look like the following:

```
CartContents
CartID          UserID      ProductID       Quantity
1               1           1               1
2               1           2               2
3               1           1               2
4               2           3               1

Gifts
ProductID       UserID      Quantity
1               1           1
2               1           1
3               3           1
```

Is it possible to construct a single query that provides one row per cart item and links the above two tables taking into account that each gift may only link to each cart item once?  Or does this need to be handled in a script?

In other words, because user 1 has product 1 in their cart twice, and they have only been promised one free product 1, the query should return a matching Gifts record for cartID 1, but not cartID 3.  The query, pulling for user ID 1, would return:

```
CartID      ProductID       Quantity        unpaidQuantity
1           1               1               0
2           2               2               1
3           1               2               2
```

Or

```
CartID      ProductID       Quantity        unpaidQuantity
1           1               1               1
2           2               2               1
3           1               2               1
```

I realize that the fact that there is more than one 'right' answer to this question raises a red flag.  In reality it doesn't matter which cart record each GC is applied to, as the end result (the price) will work out the same.  I'm perfectly happy to say the 'first' (lowest cartID) is the one that should be linked.

My assumption is that the database will be far more efficient at this than any script I could write; I'd even be willing to bet there's some crazy type of join I've never heard of specifically designed for it.  I am also assuming that any such ColdFusion script may be somewhat complicated and thus take a fair amount of development and testing time while a single query may be relatively simple (though apparently beyond my limited SQL capabilities).  If I'm incorrect in this I'd appreciate any thoughts on that as well.

My setup, if it matters:

- MySQL 5.0
- ColdFusion 9
- Windows 2000 AS

**Edit:**
It sounds like the quantity column is really going to cause issues, so let's continue assuming that quantity does not exist on the Gifts table.  It still must exist on cartContents, however.

Comment: Your server does matter.  You can solve this by getting a cumulative sum on the quantity within each order, and then joining to the gift certificate based on that quantity.  However, Mysql does not support cumulative sums directly, requiring much more complex logic.

Comment: I think that it's impossible to be done in one query if gift spreads to more than one line. I suggest doing two separate queries ordered by ProductID, then loop through both of them inside script. Another variant is to make a stored procedure that would compute everything on server side and put into temporaty table.

Comment: From the sounds of it I will need to forgo the quantity column in the Gifts table, so let's erase that from the spec.

Answer (score 1):

I thought of another way of doing this that just requires and additional group by and join.  However, it requires a unique id on CartContents.  I'm not sure i this is what CartId is supposed to be.  However, it seems that a user could have more than one cart, so I assume not.

The idea is to identify the first record for a given product in each cart.  Then, use this information when joining in the gifts.

```
select CartID, UserID, ProductID, Quantity, FirstCCId  
from CartContents cc join
     (select CartID, UserID, ProductID, min(CartContentsId) as FirstCCId
      from CartContents cc
      group by CartID, UserID, ProductID
     ) ccmin
     on cc.CartId = ccmin.CartId and cc.UserId = ccmin.UserId and
        cc.ProductId = ccmin.ProductId left outer join
     Gifts g
     on cc.ProductID= g.ProductId and cc.UserID = g.userId and
        cc.CartContentsId = ccmin.FirstCCId
```

This works when the gift is applied to only one product line row.  If the quantity for the gift is actually larger than the quantity on any given line, this query still only puts it on one line.

Comment: Thank you; I'll need a bit to wrap my head around that and then I'll give it a test ;).  Regarding cartID, it is a unique identifier for the row.  There is no table holding a header record; a user's cart is simply a collection of all records in the cart table with their user ID attached.  A header and lines is used when the order is entered, but there seems no need for it before.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
select c.cartid, c.productid, c.quantity, c.quantity -
         case 
           when (select sum(c2.quantity) from CartContents c2 
                 where c.userid = c2.userid 
                   and c.productid = c2.productid 
                   and c.cartid < c2.cartid) < 
                 (select g.quantity from gifts g 
                  where c.userid = g.userid 
                    and c.productid = g.productid) then
             (select g.quantity from gifts g 
              where c.userid = g.userid 
                and c.productid = g.productid) - 
             (select sum(c2.quantity) from CartContents c2 
              where c.userid = c2.userid 
                and c.productid = c2.productid 
                and c.cartid < c2.cartid) 
           else 0 
         end UnpaidQuantity
from CartContents c
where userid = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; I will get it a try once I get back to my server.  :)